# How to listen to redux action stream in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-observable

I'm working on a React application that uses the following architecture:

- `redux`
- `typesafe-actions`
- `redux-observable`

My question is: How can I execute an UI action on specific redux action?

For example, suppose we have the following async actions defined with `typesafe-actions`:

```
export const listTodo = createAsyncAction(
  'TODO:LIST:REQUEST',
  'TODO:LIST:SUCCESS',
  'TODO:LIST:FAILURE',
)<void, Todo[], Error>();
```

An Epic will watch for `listTodo.request()` and send the API call, then convert the response to a `listTodo.success()` action. Then the redux reducer will be triggered by `listTodo.success()` action and store the todo list into redux store.

In this setting, suppose I want to do the following things in an component:

- dispatch a `listTodo.request()` action to retrieve all the actions
- After the async request is done (i.e. after `listTodo.success()` action appears in the action stream), redirect the UI to a second path

So my question is, how could I watch the action stream and react to the `listTodo.success()` action?

**UPDATE:** To avoid being too specific, we can think of another case. I want to simply display an alert with `window.alert()` after `listTodo.success()` appears in the action stream. Or simply `console.log()`, or whatever that changes local state (instead of global redux state). Is there a way to implement that?

**UPDATE 2:** There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226681/how-to-subscribe-to-action-success-callback-using-ngrx-and-effects), but for Angular w/ ngrx. What I want to do is exactly the thing described in above post, but in React / redux-observable fashion:

```
import { Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';

@Component(...)
class SomeComponent implements OnDestroy {
    constructor(updates$: Actions) {
        updates$
            .ofType(PostActions.SAVE_POST_SUCCESS)
            .takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
            .do(() => /* hooray, success, show notification alert ect..             
            .subscribe();
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you do navigation in your app? Are you using a redux based router like `connected-react-router` ?

Comment: @Harald I don't want this question to be too specific. I know if the route is stored as redux state this problem can be solved. What if, say, I want to simply show a dialog with `window.alert()` after `listTodo.success()` is observed?

Comment: Then either create a new epic that watches for `listTodo.success()`, perform a side effect with `action$.tap(() => {window.alert()})` and then `ignoreElements()`

Comment: Thanks @Harald. Can I do this (create an epic) in a component?

Comment: You need to use `combineEpics()` to combine all the Epics in your application and run it with the `epicMiddleware`. See https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/SettingUpTheMiddleware.html how to set up `redux-observable` correctly

Comment: @Harald I started to understand your first question. Probably route should be a global state and changing route is not something a component should worry about. I'm trying to move more logics into Epics and see if I can solve all the problems.

Comment: Good luck! It's a bit tricky at the beginning, but it will become easier very quickly. And then epics will be good way to encapsulate logic and reduce global state.

Answer (score 1):

With redux the components update based on state.

If you want to update a component based on an action than you update the state in the reducer, such as setting {...state, success: true} in the reducer. From there you simply read the state into your component as you normally would and if the state is changing to success than you show your window.

Comment: Thanks @ralph-ritoch for the solution. I kind of feel that this would be less error proof - what if there are some other actions also update `success` state? what if the original async "request" action is emitted twice and the successor "success" actions' order cannot be guaranteed?

Comment: @charlee for multiple success states you just give them their own names, such as loginSuccess, fetchUserSuccess, whatever.  I regularly store state from redux into my component so when receiving the state updates from the observable I can check if the state has changed or not so if success is emitted twice it only shows once.

Comment: @charlee if you need to sync multiple results with a component than I can see the possiblity of holding an array in your state which has something such as {success: boolean, id: string} and populating id with some random or unique value. I can't think of too many times when that would be needed, but it is possible to have  a queue redux state.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like a dialogue should be a side effect, so you'd put them in epics

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, the best way to listen for actions inside a component is using the [`createListenerMiddleware`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware) that is included with the [redux-toolkit](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit) (RTK), combined with `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Could also just `return dispatch(addListener())` directly, but showing this
  // as a separate variable to be clear on what's happening
  const unsubscribe = dispatch(
    addListener({
      actionCreator: todoAdded,
      effect: (action, listenerApi) => {
        // do some useful logic here
      },
    })
  )
  return unsubscribe
}, [])
```

Docs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#adding-listeners-inside-components

I usually use Epic Observables for side effects, and use a selector for state changes in components, **but** there are certain situations where listening for an action directly inside a component (instead of a state change) is the best solution. The above fits that bill perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late but I solved a similar problem by creating a little npm module. It allows you to subscribe to and listen for redux actions and executes the provided callback function as soon as the state change is complete. Usage is as follows. In your componentWillMount or componentDidMount hook:

```
 subscribeToWatcher(this,[
      {  
        action:"SOME_ACTION",
        callback:()=>{
          console.log("Callback Working");
        },
        onStateChange:true
      },
    ]);
```

Detailed documentation can be found at  https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-action-watcher